# Data not filtering before a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

A puzzler from a coworker that I cannot figure out...

```
update  btd.dbo.tblpayroll
set     empname = ( select  b.Legal_Name
                    from    ( SELECT    Legal_Name,
                                        Employee_ID
                              FROM      Com.dbo.Workers
                              WHERE     isnumeric(Employee_ID) = 1
                            ) b
                    where   b.Employee_ID = empnum
                            and b.Legal_name is not NULL
                  )
where   empname is NULL
```

---

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N0007      ' to data type int.  The table alias b would actually be a view.

The value 'N0007       ' is in the Workers table.  I don't see why it is not being filtered from the results that are being joined.

EDIT:

The alias does, in fact, return the correct rows - so isNumeric is doing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the optimizer is attempting to apply the where clause of the outer select before the inner select.  Presumably it thinks it would be able to do an index lookup on Employee_ID resulting in a faster query in this case.  Try:

```
update  btd.dbo.tblpayroll
set     empname = ( select Legal_Name
                    from Com.dbo.Workers
                    where  isnumeric(Employee_ID) = 1
                           and convert(varchar,Employee_ID)
                             = convert(varchar,empnum) 
                           and Legal_name is not NULL)
where   empname is NULL
```

Converting them all to varchar should take care of it.  I don't think it's much less efficient than you wanted orginally since the isnumeric, if done first, would have forced a table scan anyway.

Comment: Optimizer thing I think as well. 
  where b.Employee_ID = CAST(empnum AS VARCHAR)
should help

Comment: I tried looking at the explain plan to see if I could spot it - but I'm not well versed in reading them.  Your query worked well enough in the actual query.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stanislav -- I wasn't sure what types each were so I thought converting both to varchar was the safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe N is considered currency symbol? You can try to replace IsNumeric with

```
LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]',/*length of Employee_ID*/)
```

or just

```
LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

if letter cannot be in the middle

Answer (score 0):

`ISNUMERIC()` is famously unreliable for what you are trying to do.  You'll need [an alternative, which I've been asking for here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312054/efficient-isnumeric-replacements-on-sql-server) like [this one](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing is to force the order of comparison, perhaps by getting then name from a view with only numeric Employee_IDs, rather than the full Workers table.

Comment: Unfortunatly the obvious answer is what we were doing first - and that surprisingly had the same behavior.