# SQL Server converting a variable varchar field to money/decimal/something with decimal places

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, data-conversion

I'm looking for an elegant way to convert a field of type varchar, with variable data in it, to a data type which can be used for mathematical operations sample data from the field 
(excluding quotes)

```
''
'abc'
'23'
'23.2'
```

The method should work for all, and for the first & second values should return 0, and not throw an SQL Server error..

Comment: Often when you have data of different types stored in a field, it indicates that you have a database design problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IsNumeric(YourColumn) = 0 THEN 
           0 
       ELSE 
           CAST(YourColumn AS decimal(18, 2)) 
       END
```

You have to adjust the destination data type, I have chosen decimal(18, 2) for demonstration.

Comment: IsNumeric is a nasty little function, as long as a type converts to any of the numeric types it returns 1, but you do not know which type is has agreed it can convert to, so for the input '£1.20' it will throw an error on the cast, even though it passed the isnumeric.

Comment: It is incredibly difficult to £1.2 will convert to money, which is why the IsNumeric allows it, but refuses to convert to anything else. '1e1' is numeric because it can will convert to a real or float, but not to an int, even thought the result is a whole number. I've never seen a compelling solution, it's already been covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312054/efficient-isnumeric-replacements-on-sql-server for examples of workarounds, all with pros and cons.

Comment: "Cannot convert a char value to money"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a long-dead thread, but I recently stumbled upon it from a Google search and had a thought.  It is less elegant than a CASE statement, but it is an alternative.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(LEFT(MyColumn, PATINDEX('% %', MyColumn + ' ') - 1)), 1) AS MONEY), LEFT(MyColumn, PATINDEX('% %', MyColumn + ' ') - 1))
FROM
    myTable
```

or you could do:

```
Select COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(MyColumn), 1) AS MONEY), MyColumn)
FROM
    myTable
```

The top version would see "2 5" as just 2, the bottom one would see it as a text field.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CASE IsNumeric(mycol) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(mycol AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to convert it, you should use `UPDATE` instead of `SELECT`

```
UPDATE Table
SET Col1 = CAST(Col1 As Decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` is a great option for this: Find more information [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) It evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

`ISNUMERIC` returns 0 or 1 depending on if the value being evaluated could be considered one of the SQL 'number' or 'numeric' types. e.g. int, bigint, money..

`NULLIF` essentially finds the value you specify and if it matches it replaces it with a `NULL` value.

`CAST` Simply changes a data type to another in this example to `MONEY`

As you can see, if you break the below down using this information its quite an elegant solution I think?

```
COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(COL1), 1) AS MONEY), COL1)
```