# Use Try Catch Block in UDFs in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following lines of code in my user-defined function :

```
declare @annualStr  varchar(30)
declare @annual float
    begin try
          set @annualStr = dbo.GetXMLValues(@businessId,@id)
          set @annual = convert(float,isnull(@annualStr,'0'))
    end try
    begin catch
          set @annual = 0
    end catch
```

The value comes from `dbo.GetXMLValues` may be a `varchar` value so I need to use try catch block to convert value into `float`..

But it throws an error saying.. it is invalid to use try catch blocks in UDF

Why?? And what to do to convert `varchar` value to `float` when it is unknown

Comment: The Why? Isn't really answerable except as "because they're not supported by the product"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Try\_Convert for SQL Server 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941035/try-convert-for-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 2):

Updated based on comments.

```
SET @annualstr = dbo.GetXMLValues(@businessId,@id);

IF @annualstr NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND  @annualstr NOT LIKE '%.%.%' 
  BEGIN
    SET @annual = Cast(@annualstr As float);
  END;

SET @annual = Coalesce(@annual, 0);
```

Comment: The problem with ISNUMERIC is that **SELECT ISNUMERIC('$')** also returns 1

Comment: Updated my answer to have a more robust comparison. Only allowing numeric values with a maximum of one period.

Comment: its not working. sometimes i gets £400000 value and it goes into casting the value to float and it gives an error : Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani are you sure..? `SELECT '£400000' WHERE '£400000' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND '£400000' NOT LIKE '%.%.%'`

Comment: it checks and returns true in the condition but when converting the value into float, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, if you're using SQL 2012+ Then you can use the new [`Try_Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) function

```
SET @annualStr = dbo.GetXMLValues(@businessId,@id);
SET @annual = Coalesce(Try_Cast(@annualStr As float), 0);
```