# Convert full column from nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question how can I convert a SQL Server column with data of type `nvarchar` to float?

Classic query:

```
ALTER TABLE <column>
ALTER COLUMN <column> FLOAT;
```

works only with an empty column.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add new float column, copy data, remove old column, rename new column?

Comment: your code is almost correct just replace the first <column> by tablename

Comment: I Have 54 column where I need change data type. I guess I needed something more automatic

Answer (score 1):

Normal classic query works even with columns having data, not only empty ones. But the issue arises when the `Nvarchar` column holds incompatible data. So best option is to create a new table or create new column and use [Try_Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)..
(only from SQL Server 2012)

**This works:**

```
create table #t
(
    id nvarchar(3)
)

insert into #t
    select 1
    union all
    select 2

alter table #t
alter column id float--this works
```

**This fails:**

```
create table #t
(
   id nvarchar(3)
)

insert into #t
select 1
union all
select 2

insert into #t
select 'a'

alter table #t
alter column id float--this fails
```

So best way is to use `try_convert` and take decision on null values which is incompatible data

```
create table #t1
(
    id float
)

insert into #t1
    select try_convert(float, id) 
    from #t
```

**Update:**

If you are on SQL Server 2008 R2 or below, you can use this technique instead  of `TRY_Convert`. Taken from [Mikael excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942602/2975396)

```
declare @T table
(
  Col varchar(50)
)

insert into @T values
('1'),
('1.1'),
('1,1'),
('1a')

select cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("Col") cast as xs:decimal ?', 
                             'decimal(28,10)') as Col
from @T
```

**Output:**

```
Col
-------------
1.0000000000
1.1000000000
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: When I try this script:create table #t1
(
id float
)

insert into #t1
select try_convert(float,id) from #t so in new table is only <NULL> value..

Comment: New table you will have 1,2,null values

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and not available to users of an earlier version of SQL Server

Comment: Thanks @marc_s,since user didnt mentioned the version,i didnt paid mcuh attention to it.will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

Comment: Its the same problem.