# How to convert varchar(4) to float in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion, sql-convert

I'm trying to convert my database fields from `VARCHAR(4)` to `FLOAT`. Some of the values in these fields might not be digits since these fields didn't have any validation prior. My main target is to convert any `integer` or `decimal` value in float format and save in new database field. For this process I use `INSERT SELECT STATEMENT` from old table into the new table. So far I have this line of code for my conversion:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2))) <> 0 AND ISNUMERIC(hs_td2) = 1 THEN CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2)) AS float) ELSE NULL END AS hs_td2
```

First step I trim the value then check if it's numeric and then convert to float otherwise set to NULL. With the code above I'm getting this error message in Microsoft Studio:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 13
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

Line 13th is beginning of my `SELECT` statement. Then I tried this conversion as well:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2))) <> 0 AND ISNUMERIC(hs_td2) = 1 THEN CONVERT(FLOAT, LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2))) ELSE NULL END AS hs_td2
```

and I got the same error message. Values in my fields could be something like this:

10 or 5 or -10 or 0.9 or 11.6 or -11.89 and so on...

I'm wondering if `isNumeric()` is the best function that I should use and why my code produces the error message listed above?

If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Might not be those values.  `select cast('-11.89' as float)` executes successfully.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm wondering if NULL values can cause some problems?

Comment: Try `hs_td2 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' OR '-' + hs_td2 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'` (invert the condition and use a `SELECT` first if you want to see invalid values). This still does not guarantee that the conversion will succeed (`1.1.1` slips through this way), but at least it filters alphanumerics.

Comment: `-11.89` will not fit into a `varchar(4)` field...

Comment: @HansKesting I made mistake. Everything will be rounded to one decimal after period.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try\_Convert for SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941035/try-convert-for-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 2):

No, `ISNUMERIC` is not the best function to use.

Essentially, this question has been asked before, though not in this wording:

[Try_Convert for SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17941035/4116017)

The most upvoted answer recommends to cast to XML to use XML-specific casting function:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (v varchar(4));

INSERT INTO @T (v) VALUES
('1g23'),
('-1.8'),
('11.6'),
('akjh'),
('.'),
('-'),
('$'),
('12,5');


select
    cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("V") cast as xs:float ?', 'float') as new_v
from @T
```

---

I'll leave my first version of the answer below.

Most likely you are getting the conversion error because the server tries to run `CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2)) AS float)` for each row of the table, not only for those that are numeric.

This usually happens when you try to filter out non-numeric rows using the `WHERE ISNUMERIC(...) = 1` filter. Technically it may happen in `CASE` expression as well.

That's why they added `TRY_CONVERT` in 2012.

I'd try to write my own user-defined function that uses `TRY-CATCH` and tries to convert the given value. Yes, it will be slow.

---

Having said that, the example below with `CASE` runs fine:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (v varchar(4));

INSERT INTO @T (v) VALUES
('123'),
('-1.8'),
('11.6'),
('akjh'),
('123');

SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v) = 1 THEN CAST(v AS float) ELSE NULL END AS new_v
FROM @T;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+
| new_v |
+-------+
| 123   |
| -1.8  |
| 11.6  |
| NULL  |
| 123   |
+-------+
```

But, if I put a `.` or `-` or `$` value, like so:

```
INSERT INTO @T (v) VALUES
('123'),
('-1.8'),
('11.6'),
('akjh'),
('$');
```

The query fails:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

There may be other special characters and their combinations that `ISNUMERIC` would not complain about. That's why I originally said that overall, `ISNUMERIC` is not the best function to use.

If it is a one-off conversion, you can try to build a `LIKE` expression to catch all special cases that are present in your data, but if you need a reliable generic solution, upgrade to 2012+ and use `TRY_CONVERT` or write your T-SQL UDF, or your CLR UDF.

Comment: Well for some reason my statement is failing... I see few rows in SQL Studio and then error message shows. I'm not sure which value is causing statement to fail.

Comment: This code will fail for smth like this: INSERT INTO @T (v) VALUES
('12,4')

Comment: @sepupic, yes, `ISNUMERIC` is not the best function to use as I said from the start.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, if you have the problem with ',', just add condition on it like this: SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v) = 1 and v not like '%,%' THEN CAST(v AS float) ELSE NULL END AS new_v
FROM @T;

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov We are now trying to catch the characters that provoke the error. If we are fortunate and it's just a comma, we'll fix it by adding a condition like in my comment above

Comment: @sepupic, I found that this has been answered before. I've added a link.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlxml has enough power to make magic. Of course, the performance is the problem. But still better, than million of conditions

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (v varchar(4));

INSERT INTO @T (v) VALUES
('123'),('-1.8'),('11.6'),('akjh'),('$'),('-.'),('-.1'),(NULL);

declare @Xml xml = (SELECT v  FROM @T T for xml auto,elements);

select T.v.value('v[1]','varchar(4)') v, T.v.value('max(v[1])','float') converted_v 
from @xml.nodes('/T') T(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the values in your varchar columns

ISNUMBER() for vaule such as **'.'** and **'-'** will return 1, however, it will failed when you CAST to FLOAT

ISNUMBER() for value such as **'3D2**' , **'1e2**' will return 1, and can be CAST to FLOAT, however, you may not want consider it as number.

You may try the following to convert

```
CASE WHEN 
  not LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2))like '%[^0-9.,-]%'    -- Value only contains 0-9 . -
  and LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2)) not like '.'          -- can not be only .
  and LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2)) not like '-'          -- can not be only -
  and isnumeric(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2))) = 1  
THEN CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2)) AS float) 
ELSE NULL 
END
```

Comment: How to prevent those non numeric values in the case statement ? Also should I use LTRIM(RTRIM(Value)) ?

Comment: With the statement that you provided above all values are NULL in hs_td2 column for every row.

Comment: it seems you have spaces. You may need replace hs_td2 with LTRIM(RTRIM(hs_td2))