# SQL Filter numbers between x and x and ignore strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table in SQL Server where I need to filter rooms by name and type. The problem is, that the names are stored as `varchar` and there are also some rooms with letters. I need to filter out the rooms with letters before I can compare them as `int` or otherwhise I will get an error.

Here's an example from Room.Name:

```
030
210a
210b
Lan-Room-A
240
```

I can work around the room names with `a` or `b` with `LEFT(Rooms.Name, 3)` but if I want to add `(LEFT(Rooms.Name, 3) BETWEEN 0 and 350` and it gets to `Lan-Room-A` it oviously can't convert a string to int. I also need to do additional filtering like `Room.Type = 6` for example.

```
SELECT
    Room.Name,
    Room.Descr,
    Room.MainUser
WHERE
    LEFT(Room.Name, 1) NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
    AND LEFT(Room.Name, 3) BETWEEN 0 AND 350  
    AND Room.Type = 6
```

(Removed some joins for simplicity)

I simply need to filter out the rows which contain strings before the when clause, but I have no idea how.

Do you guys have any idea?

Please note that I can't edit the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the issue.  You can use strings:

```
WHERE Room.Name NOT LIKE '[0-9]%' AND
      LEFT(Room.Name, 3) BETWEEN '0' AND '350' AND  
      Room.Type = 6
```

However, I suspect your intention is captured by:

```
WHERE Room.Name >= '000' AND
      Room.Name < '351' AND
      Room.Type = 6
```

This works because you have zero-padded the numbers, so string comparisons will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `TRY_CAST`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Rooms
WHERE TRY_CAST(LEFT(Rooms.Name, 3) AS INT) BETWEEN 0 and 350;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ec741e17836193b71bc9e9b5d4c9c926)**

---

Your second approach is not guaranteed to work even with correct check:

```
WHERE LEFT(Room.Name, 1) NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
  AND LEFT(Room.Name, 3) BETWEEN 0 AND 350  
  and Room.Type = 6
```

Query optimizer could check conditions in any order so `LEFT(Room.Name, 3) BETWEEN 0 AND 350` could yield conversion error.

Comment: @SnakeFoot Yes, you are right. Please also note that SQL Server 2008 extended support will end on July 9 2019.

Comment: thnx. nice to know as my office server is still on 2008

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but sadly its MSSQL 2008 (for now). I will try it next week when we switch to a MS SQL 2016. If it works, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941035/try-convert-for-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 0):

For 2008. Please use this.

**Solution-**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT '030' a UNION ALL
    SELECT '210a' UNION ALL
    SELECT '210b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lan-Room-A' UNION ALL
    SELECT '240'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE 
PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', a) = 1 AND
1 = CASE WHEN CAST(LEFT(a, 3) AS INT) BETWEEN 0 and 350 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a
----------
030
210a
210b
240

(4 rows affected)
```