# SQL Server: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric depending on WHERE condition used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with a table that has an `NVARCHAR` ID column and another two `NVARCHAR` columns that have only decimal values, but I'm not at liberty to alter the schema.

Using `CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18,6))`, I am able to perform the required calculations on the data where querying a single ID, but I get a conversion error when querying 2 IDs.

Consider two IDs, 'TEST1', AND 'TEST2', the following will work fine

```
SELECT ID, CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS FOO 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE ID = 'TEST1'
```

This will also work fine

```
SELECT ID, CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS FOO 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE ID = 'TEST2'
```

This however will produce an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

```
SELECT ID, CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS FOO 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE ID = 'TEST1' OR ID = 'TEST2'
```

How should I handle this?

Comment: oh, sorry, typo in my question...

Comment: ok, the question is fixed now. yeah, I've been programming in SQL Server 2008 for years and I've never had this problem. I can't begin to imagine what could cause a conversion error ONLY if both records are returned in the result set, but not either or

Comment: I think you have to give us the actual data in those 2 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the execution path.  Based on your first two queries, the following should return a valid result set:

```
SELECT ID, CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS FOO
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID = 'TEST1' OR ID = 'TEST2';
```

Unfortunately, what is happening is that SQL Server is deciding to do a full table scan *and* pushing the `cast()` closer to the data.  Some value of `FIELD` other than `'TEST1'` or `'TEST2'` is causing the problem.

I consider this a bug.  Regardless of my opinion, there is an easy fix in SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18, 6)) AS FOO
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID = 'TEST1' OR ID = 'TEST2';
```

In SQL Server 2008 (which will soon no longer be supported), you can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ID,
       (CASE WHEN FIELD NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND
                  FIELD NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
             THEN CAST(FIELD AS DECIMAL(18, 6))
        END) AS FOO
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID = 'TEST1' OR ID = 'TEST2';
```

Instead of failing, this will return `NULL`, which is simply ignored.  Also you should use `ID IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')` instead of `OR`, but that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: This post is tagged SQL Server 2008, in which `TRY_CAST` doesn't exist. This post provides a (rather ugly) workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941035/try-convert-for-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not know regex could be used that way in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Also, very useful information about how CAST is handled in the SQL pipeline

Comment: Use with extreme caution, I suppose

Comment: @Jace there are many good reasons for using the `correct` datatype when designing a database - this is one of them.

Comment: It's worth noting that this can suddenly start happening on queries that have been working for a while.  I have complex queries over large datasets, and it's not uncommon for older code to fail for this exact reason just due to changes in the underlying data and the way the statistics are collected on the table.

Comment: @MathewPaxinos This is exactly what happened to me at work today and I was really thrown for a loop

Comment: @DaleBurrell Believe me, you are preaching to the quire.