# Alternative to try_convert for lower compatibility level on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pymssql

I am trying to run my query on a SQL Server 2008 where the compatibility level doesn't support `try_convert()`.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    A.PTNTIDNO,
    A.LR,
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.ITEM1, '') = ''
        THEN (select ROUND(AVG(TRY_CONVERT(float, ITEM1)),3) from INFLABD)
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT(float,A.ITEM1, 3)
    FROM INFLABD AS A
    WHERE A.LR = 'R'
    AND A.PTNTIDNO = %s
    ORDER BY A.REGDATE DESC
```

Error message

> File "src\pymssql_pymssql.pyx", line 478, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
> pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (195, b"'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.DB-Lib error message
> 20018

Therefore, is there another alternative?

Follow your comment

```
cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("A.RIGHT01") cast as xs:decimal ?', 'decimal(28,10)')
```

It worked well

but add aggregate function 'AVG'

```
THEN (select ROUND(AVG(cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("A.RIGHT01") cast as xs:decimal ?', 'decimal(28,10)')),3) from OPERATIONDATA)
```

Error message

> Column 'OPERATIONDATA.RIGHT01' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.DB-Lib error message 20018

Add
I solve the problem just change 'A.RIGHT01' to 'RIGHT01'

And now I'm curious about the query

```
THEN (select ROUND(AVG(cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("RIGHT01") cast as xs:decimal ?', 'decimal(28,10)')),3) from OPERATIONDATA)
```

Can explain this query..? I don't know why this is working well

1. Is this only used as a alternative for when try_convert is not possible?
2. I learned sql but this code is never seen before. So can explain?

`cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("RIGHT01") cast as xs:decimal ?', 'decimal(28,10)'`

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Other companies are managing db, but compatibility is not solved. be looking for an alternative to

Comment: do you mean the SQL Server that you are using does not support `TRY_CONVERT()`?

Comment: yes, other db company work well but the other company not work this query. after searching google i found the problem is compatibility, but i can't request that company solve the problem

Comment: So something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941035/try-convert-for-sql-server-2008-r2) then?

Comment: Okay , I edited

Comment: [Simulating TRY_CONVERT() in SQL Server 2008](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5411/simulating-tryconvert-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: I'm trying your comment but xml? is working? Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `A` refers to the outer reference of `INFLABD` but you want to refer to the inner table. Effectively, what you need is `sql:column("od.RIGHT01")`

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    A.PTNTIDNO,
    A.LR,
    ROUND(
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.ITEM1, '') = ''
        THEN (select AVG(cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("od.RIGHT01") cast as xs:decimal ?', 'decimal(28,10)') from OPERATIONDATA od)
        ELSE cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("A.ITEM1") cast as xs:decimal ?', 'decimal(28,10)')
      END, 3)
    FROM INFLABD AS A
    WHERE A.LR = 'R'
    AND A.PTNTIDNO = %s
    ORDER BY A.REGDATE DESC
```