# Cast giving an error

Tags: sql-server

Why is this simple code giving me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3.0' to data type
>   int.

```
select cast(value as INT)  
from CV3BasicObservation  (nolock)
where value >= 110
```

Comment: What data type is the `value` column?

Comment: Is somewhat surprising that `cast('3.0' as int)` doesn't work but why are you storing numbers in a varchar column anyway?

Comment: I don't understand the question, the error message is already telling you everything you need to know, it cannot convert the varchar value '3.0' to data type int. Clearly that is why that code is giving you an error.

Comment: some how I have to get the values greater than 110, I totally understood the error message

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server doesn't want to convert a number string that looks like a decimal to integer because you could lose precision.  You could trick it with the round function:

```
select cast(round(value,0) as INT)  
from CV3BasicObservation  (nolock)
where cast(round(value,0) as INT) >= 110
```

NOTE: You have to do it to all instances of the field `value` where you are explicitly converting it to `int` or where it is implicitly converting it for comparison an `int` type value.

Comment: You have to do it to all instances that you used the field in your query. See edits to my answer.

Comment: I did add that, even then I am getting the same error - Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: The values where it is giving error is in 0.2 and <0.01

Comment: You must have other non-numeric data in some of your fields.

Comment: These are the different types of values in this column                               0.2
134
4.9
93
29
80
5.5
<0.01
1.3
<2
<70
06MAY08
06-11-05
ALX 1604
9.81
109.5
2130
EZF 6592
>220
2
0000
-68.7

Comment: You have to have numeric values... you can't convert convert '<0.01', 'ALX', or '06MAY08' to an integer.

Comment: I do not want to convert them, I just need to filter the numeric values that are greater than or equal to 110

Comment: I tried the following , But this is giving me an error   'An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

select cast(Value as int) as value
from CV3BasicObservation with (nolock)
where 1 = case when value like '%[^0-9]%' then 0
when cast(value as int) > 110 then 1
else 0 end

Comment: Do you have SQL Server 2012?  If so the TRY_PARSE function might be of help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx otherwise check out this post for filtering numeric data in strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312054/efficient-isnumeric-replacements-on-sql-server

Comment: I believe "CAST(ROUND(CAST('3.0' AS float), 0) AS int)" would be more effective.

Comment: They are identical in function.  The string is implicitly converted to float and then rounded, but explicitly casting to float is more verbose so it's not a bad idea to make it clear what is going on.