# Specific column -- Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is part of the T-SQL.I am getting below error. Can anyone guide me.The issue is because of the **value** column which is of **nvarchar** datatype

```
SELECT RuleID, SourceID, DataFileID, ChildCount, DP_State 
FROM        
(SELECT DP_State.RuleID, CAST(DP_State.SourceID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SourceID, CAST(DP_State.DataFileID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DataFileID, ChildCount, DP_State
FROM (
        SELECT  RuleID ,
                RuleResultID ,
                CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ISNULL([ResultValue], 0)) = 1 THEN                      
                CAST(ISNULL([Value], 0) AS BIGINT)
ELSE
                    -1
                END AS ChildCount,
```

Error I am getting :

[image]

Comment: `ISNUMERIC()` [is unreliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312054/efficient-isnumeric-replacements-on-sql-server), `SELECT ISNUMERIC(ISNULL([ResultValue], 0)), ResultValue` and see where there is an unexpected `1`

Comment: Hi @AlexK.,I have executed SELECT ISNUMERIC(ISNULL([ResultValue], 0)), ResultValue and there are many 1 in a column along with ResultValue.

Comment: You can use TRY_CAST() instead of CAST() to see where you get a NULL VALUE (Thats the one vlaue TRY_CAST coudn't cast).

Comment: See the link in my comment, `ISNUMERIC` thinks a value like `'.'` *is* numeric but casting it to a numeric type will fail with the error you encounter.

Comment: @AlexK., that's correct, ISNUMERIC considers +- also as numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later

```
SELECT RuleID,
    SourceID,
    DataFileID,
    ChildCount,
    DP_State
FROM (
    SELECT DP_State.RuleID,
        CAST(DP_State.SourceID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SourceID,
        CAST(DP_State.DataFileID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DataFileID,
        ChildCount,
        DP_State
    FROM (
        SELECT RuleID,
            RuleResultID,
            CASE 
                WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, ISNULL([ResultValue],0)) IS NOT NULL
                    THEN CAST(ISNULL([Value], 0) AS BIGINT)
                ELSE - 1
                END AS ChildCount,
        )
    )
```

Comment: @Thanks for your help.It fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad I could assist.@SQLBoy

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly casting to an integer by first checking `[value]` against `0` in `ISNULL()`. Only after that you are casting to an integer, instead try the following:

Evaluate against a string:

```
CAST(ISNULL([Value], '0') AS BIGINT)
```

Or first cast to an integer:

```
ISNULL(CAST([Value] AS BIGINT), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Aquillo,it help me to realize my issue.