# IF NOT EXIST insert ELSE IF update ELSE IF EXISTS and is not Numeric DELETE From WHERE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to modify the Stored Procedure below.

```
@UserID INT
@Unlock VARCHAR(4)

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblUnlockCode WHERE iUserID = @UserID)
BEGIN
IF ISNUMERIC(@Unlock) = 1
BEGIN 
INSERT dbo.tblUnlockCode (iUserID, sUnlockCode) VALUES (@UserID, @Unlock)
END
```

I would actually like to add to it, to where if the iUserID exists Update the @Unlock to the new Pin, and if the iUserID exists on the table but the @Unlock gets erased on the textfield(in access) it gets removed from the Table. I only want to store the iUserIDs that 4 digit pins. How could I do that?

P.S. on access I am checking if the pin is 4 digits.

Comment: Not related, but, for one example, this four "digit" PIN `SELECT ISNUMERIC('$0.0')` returns `1`. Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312054/efficient-isnumeric-replacements-on-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I also recommend adding error handling if you have none):

```sql
    @UserID INT
    @Unlock VARCHAR(4)

    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tblUnlockCode WHERE iUserID = @UserID)
    BEGIN
      IF ISNUMERIC(@Unlock) = 1
      BEGIN 
        INSERT dbo.tblUnlockCode (iUserID, sUnlockCode) VALUES (@UserID, @Unlock)
      END   
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      IF ISNUMERIC(@Unlock) = 1
      BEGIN 
        UPDATE dbo.tblUnlockCode set sUnlockCode=@Unlock WHERE iUserID= @UserID
      END   
      ELSE --Assuming you want to clear the record if unlock code is empty
      BEGIN
        DELETE dbo.tblUnlockCode WHERE iUserID= @UserID      
      END
    END
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, however wouldn't DELETE dbo.tblUnlockCode erase the whole table? It's a little nerve wrecking using anything to do with Delete.

Comment: @Cookies: delete statement has ```WHERE iUserID= @UserID```. It will delete all records for a particular UserID but not all records. If that's not what you want, you can change it.

Comment: Okay no it sounds like it does what i want it to do. Thanks !

Comment: I am having some trouble with the BEGINs and ENDs. I keep getting an error. I added a third END in the end but now it doesn't seem to read the send else statement. I update a user and it does not update in the table.

Comment: @Cookies: "END" was missing before the first "ELSE". I fixed it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help.